# Linux kernel module hwsim is only creating only one Wifi interface instead of 2 or more

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, wifi, kernel-modules

The Linux kernel provides the `mac80211_hwsim` module to create virtual Wifi interfaces for testing, it should create at least 2 interfaces, like `wlan0` and `wlan1` but in my case it's creating a single one.

I'm following this: https://feldspaten.org/2020/04/01/a-virtual-wlan-network-in-linux/

I need this to test Wifi during the installation of Arch Linux, so the environment is the Arch Linux installer.

When I run:

```bsh
modprobe mac80211_hwsim
ip link
```

I'm getting:
[image]

As you can see I'm only getting a `wlan1`.

Even if I run `modprobe mac80211_hwsim radios=4` I'm still only having a single `wlan1`.

How can I have at least 2 virtual Wifi interfaces to have a connection between the two?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out, if you execute `modprobe mac80211_hwsim` it only creates a single interface, if you unload the module `modprobe -r mac80211_hwsim` and load it again you end up with 2 interfaces.

Also if you try to load the module again passing the `radios` parameters with the module already loaded it won't work, but with the module unloaded then you can load it passing the `radios` and it works.